# React Stytch has not been loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, stytch

Recently I get to implement Stytch to a React based application. Implementation is pretty simple and strait forward. However got into an error or bug which become a big road block for me.

I tried Googling to find solution, if not even I find similar so that I can debug myself but unfortunately didn't find any. And the big surprise if Stytch GitHub repo link provided on NPM is invalid too.

The problem I'm facing is, it says:

```
Stytch has not been loaded.
Make sure the script tag exists in the document head:

<script src="https://js.stytch.com/stytch.js"></script>

If using Next.js be sure to load Stytch using the beforeInteractive strategy in pages/_app.jsx:

import Script from 'next/script';

<Script src="https://js.stytch.com/stytch.js" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
```

I'm following the Stytch doc here: https://stytch.com/docs/sdks/javascript-sdk/email-magic-links/methods

And created a Sample app here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stytch-login-auth-xmf5r4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stytch-login-auth-forked-q4llnx?file=/public/index.html)
just install `@stytch/stytch-react` using npm.

in the code box you can add through dependencies tab.
just make sure you include the `script` tag in the `public/index.html`.

Comment: Adding Stytch `<script>` tag explicitly to `index.html` worked very well. But I'm still confused why explicitly if Stytch React library already do this? During debug I found the script tag was already there, hence I've to set explicitly! Hmm 

Comment: The `script` tag [loads](https://stytch.com/docs/sdks/javascript-sdk/getting-started) the `SDK` then you initialise the `SDK` with `initStytch`.